# BelongsTo relationship in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to have a one to many relationship, each Customer can be assigned to multiple entries, here are my migration tables

customers table:

```
Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('idtype');
        $table->string('idnumber');
        $table->string('company');
        $table->timestamps();
```

and here is my assignee table:

```
  Schema::create('assignees', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('cabinet');
            $table->time('timein');
            $table->time('timeout');
            $table->string('refnumber');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('customer_id')->unsigned()->index()->nullable();
```

here is my assignee controller where the belongs to function:

```
  class Assignee extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = [
        'cabinet', 'customer_id','timein','timeout','refnumber',
    ];

    public function cust()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
    }
}
```

and here is my index.blade.php

```
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Entry id:</th>
        <th>Person Name</th>
        <th>Referance No:</th>
        <th>timein</th>
        <th>timeout</th>
        <th width="280px">Action</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($assignees as $assignee)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
        <td>{{ $assignee->id }}</td>
        <td>{{$assignee->customer-name}}</td>
        <td>{{ $assignee->refnumber }}</td>
        <td>{{ $assignee->timein }}</td>
        <td>{{ $assignee->timeout }}</td>
```

when running the page I am getting the following error:

```
Use of undefined constant name - assumed 'name' (View: /Users/user/Documents/Laravel/blog/resources/views/assignees/index.blade.php)
```

When creating the "Assignee, laravel is not enforcing the relation checks,

what am I doing wrong? should i declare the relationship in the migration folder or having it in the Model is enough?

Comment: You lost `>` in line `<td>{{$assignee->customer-name}}</td>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your code.

1. There is a syntax error in this line. Which throws the mentioned issue.

   ```
   <td>{{$assignee->customer-name}}</td>
   ```

   It should be

   ```
   <td>{{$assignee->customer->name}}</td>
   ```
2. But, You named your relationship as `cust` not `customer`. So you need to fix that as well.

   ```
   <td>{{$assignee->cust->name}}</td>
   ```

This should fix your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here `<td>{{$assignee->customer-name}}</td>`

it should be `<td>{{$assignee->cust->name}}</td>` and you missed this `->`  so it assumed that name is a constatnt.

Answer (score -1):

You should try this;

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Entry id:</th>
        <th>Person Name</th>
        <th>Referance No:</th>
        <th>timein</th>
        <th>timeout</th>
        <th width="280px">Action</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($assignees as $assignee)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
        <td>{{ $assignee->id }}</td>
        <td>{{$assignee->customer->name}}</td>
        <td>{{ $assignee->refnumber }}</td>
        <td>{{ $assignee->timein }}</td>
        <td>{{ $assignee->timeout }}</td>
```